# how to pass multiple values(comma separated) single variable in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to pick the count based on given parameter value in a function.function parameter value can be 'I' or 'D' or 'ALL'. 'ALL' means I and D both.

for ex:

```
  create or replace function test1( FLAG in varchar2) return varchar2

    as 

    b varchar2(20);
    c varchar2(20);

    begin
    if flag='ALL'
    then 
    c:='I','D';
    else 
    c:=FLAG;
    end if;
    select count(*) into b from test where id=c;

    return b;

    end;
```

if i pass I or D its working fine.I want to pass 'ALL' as in parameter to pick all the count for both (I,D) but I am facing error.

Let me know if any other info required at my end.

Comment: try operator IN instead of =

Comment: i have tried in also .its not working for parameter 'ALL'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this, all over complicated for your scenario. It'd be easier if you used the logic from your IF statement in your SQL:

```
select count(*) into b from test where flag = 'ALL' or id = flag
```

Thus, if you pass in the `FLAG` ALL then you get everything in the table, otherwise if `FLAG` is not ALL then you restrict it to the specific value. If you want to restrict the ID to only the 2 values mentioned then you could do this:

```
select count(*) into b 
  from test 
 where ( flag = 'ALL' and id in ('I','D') )
    or id = flag
```

Comment: From what you've got in your question this will work fine @user2862073; have you tried it and if it doesn't work what _exactly_ does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

If else block needs to be changed to meet your requirements. Updated code is listed below.

create or replace function test1( flag_var in varchar2) return varchar2

as

```
count_num NUMBER(20);

begin

  if flag_var='ALL'
   then 
      select count(*) into count_num from TEST where ID in ('I' , 'D');
  else 
     select count(*) into count_num from TEST where ID = flag_var;
  end if;

return count_num;
```

end;